# MOSS 2010 Folder Permission Propagation

Tags: 2007

I have a folder structure as follows;

Root 
-> SubFolder1
---> SubFolder2
------> SubFolder3

When i stop inheriting permissions at SubFolder3 and grant contribute permission to a user directly, MOSS 2010 grants the contribute permission to Root and all of its child folders. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: @Stefan - please just flag for migration, don't advise in the comments. Otherwise we just end up with unnecessary cross posting because new users thing that's the correct thing to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does it grant 'Contribute' permission or 'Limited Access'?

Basically if you do this in SubFolder3:

john smith      permission level: contribute

Then it should do this in Root, SubFolder1 and SubFolder2

john smith      permission level: limited access

This is just to show that the user has permissions in some area of the site.